# Panic happened when create VM from live system ISO created myself

Tags: grub2, live-cd, cd-image, isolinux

:cry:
I followed this instruction:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=688872

Panic:
panic - not syncing attempted to kill init

Could you plz help me out ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nt2cP.png)

Comment: Thx for the reply. My source VM is:
4.15.0-169-generic #177-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 3 10:50:38 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.
-------
The new /boot dir has :
config-4.15.0-169-generic  grub                           initrd.img-4.15.0-55-generic   System.map-4.15.0-55-generic  vmlinuz-4.15.0-55-generic
config-4.15.0-55-generic   initrd.img-4.15.0-169-generic  System.map-4.15.0-169-generic  vmlinuz-4.15.0-169-generic

Comment: lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:security-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
---------
I followed the instruction here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=688872
---------
newly ~/cd structure is the same as instructed, but still the same situation..... :(